# Silverlight Outlook Bar

Tags: silverlight-4.0, azure

I am was looking for an outlook bar control or the xaml to make it look like one just like the one on the windows azure. I cant imagine that microsoft uses a third party control

Thanks in advance

[image: http://filedb.experts-exchange.com/incoming/2011/03_w14/t438210/Untitled.png]

Comment: Sorry for asking... - but which one is the Outlook bar? The ribbon across the top? Or one of the side bars? Or the little control with the search bar? (I haven't used Outlook this Millenium!)

Comment: It sthe one on the left with the Home, reporting, etc. When you click on the option you want then the sub options show at the top left

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean the Ribbon across the top, there's a few.

a free one on CodePlex:
http://slribbon.codeplex.com/

And from vendors:

http://www.telerik.com/products/silverlight/ribbonbar.aspx

http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/Silverlight/Bars/

If you mean the bit down the side it's easy enought with a stackpanel.

Comment: The stackpanel did it, Thanks